# Bluetooth Device Discovery Python-Android Studio

Tags: python, android-studio, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

I'm making an android app that needs to search for computers with my python app executing. I tried using pybluez in python to create and advertise a service, but i can't find documentation for how to find it with android studio.

The python app doesn't seem to be the problem, but i can't really figure out how service discovery works in android studio.

Comment: Do you want to use Bluetooth Classic or Bluetooth Low Energy?

Comment: Bt classic would be my choice, but i don't know what's the best.

Comment: The best always depends on your requirements ;) Bluetooth classic can find all other Bluetooth classic devices and filter for the name. Bluetooth Low Energy allows you to advertise a service on your PC and your smartphone to find only devices with this service. So if you only want to find devices and do not have any requirements for further data exchange I would choose BLE.

Comment: The Android developer guide has examples for both [Bluetooth Classic](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth) and [Bluetooth Low Energy](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth/ble-overview).

Comment: how can I use ble with pybluez? I found something online but it's only to find them, not advertising.

Comment: If you want to use pybluez then I think you will have to go with Bluetooth Classic. I don't believe that pybluez support the BLE Peripheral role.

Comment: As pybluez says on it's github repo, it is a project that is not under active development. Much of the ( Bluetooth Classic) functionality can be achieved with the Python socket library. Here is a blog giving more details: http://blog.kevindoran.co/bluetooth-programming-with-python-3/